# Think of something or think something

Tags: grammar

Can we use "think" without "of"?

Like: When I think writing, I think trouble.

I've seen it written like that a couple of times.

Comment: Think different. Good Luck!

Comment: It's not the same as "think of" here, but much more than that. It's an idiomatic phrasing and as such comes with an idiomatic meaning and significance. Please delve a little deeper and discover.

Comment: @Kris 'Think different' is famous only because Apple broke the rules. It is properly used as 'think differently'.

Answer (score 0):

The verb `think` has many senses. I believe the sense you're referring to is "call to mind" (Sense 2.3 in [this Oxford entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/think.))

Strictly speaking, `think of` is the more common way of using it in this sense. However, you're right that it can be used without the `of`. I'd call it a  creative use. It does get the message across. In my experience, it's used when the speaker wants to sound snappy, so it's less common in everyday conversation and more in slogans and such.

There is one exception where it's used conversationally very often. When you say `think` to mean "picture something of that variety". As in:

"Have you decided on the menu for the party yet?"
"Oh yeah. It's gonna be amazing. Nachos. Tacos. Tortillas. Think Mexican food."

PS - The `think different` discussion is irrelevant. `Different` is an adverb in that sentence and you can't use `of` before adverbs without changing the meaning and possibly even removing all meaning. (*"Think of different")