# Why in "think about/of" and "talk about" the "of" and "about" sometimes are omitted?

Tags: grammar, speech, omissibility

I sometimes see, more often of late, that in sentences like this:

> There're less known but high performing currencies: think of Georgian Larry, Armenian Dram.

"of" or "about" get omitted:

> There're less known but high performing currencies: think Georgian Larry, Armenian Dram.

or

> There're less known but high performing currencies: I'm talking Georgian Larry, Armenian Dram.

I see it happen in writing too.

Is this the latest trend, to talk this way? Or has it always been grammatically correct?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [think of something, or think something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/475836/think-of-something-or-think-something) (closed for lack of research).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways of using words change with time; it's not really a question of whether something is grammatically correct, just whether it's standard usage. People used to say "I think it fortunate that...", but now we would say "I think it's (it is) fortunate that..."

"Think XYZ" meaning "Think of" or "For example, XYZ" is just another change in usage that has happened in recent years.

Comment: There's no answer to my question in that. The question can be answered simply - yes or no. I don't need a story.  And the standard usage doesn't imply that one may speak whatever way he considers correct.

Comment: Well, all right - yes, it's a changing trend.  By _standard usage_ I meant 'the normal way of saying it at that particular time' - these things change gradually, but I suppose every change must have started with someone expressing themselves in a different way for the first time.

Comment: @kosmosu05 Standard usage (and grammaticality is usage-driven, like it or not) changes over time (see [Garner's approach at considerable.com/life/language/grammar-rules-changed](https://www.considerable.com/life/language/grammar-rules-changed/)), and even over geographical area ('He threw it out the window' is not standard in the UK).  This is one where acceptability (and gradual adoption as standard usage) is changing. _Think_ and _talk_ used as quotative-like verbs. I'd say these are acceptable in all but very formal contexts. 85% say. _Not_ a yes/no question.